# Are there Thunderbird keyboard shortcuts for tags #10, #11, #12 etc?

Tags: email, thunderbird, tags

In my Thunderbird setup I use over 20 tags. I can use keys 1-9 to apply one of the first nine tags to a message. Are there keyboard shortcuts for the 10th, 11th etc tags? Failing that, is there a way to create such keyboard shortcuts? I wouldn't reorder my tags because that would disrupt how colours are applied.

Comment: Which operating system ? How did you assign the keys 1-9 ?

Comment: The short answer is no, they are coded in to be 1 to 9.  You could try a recording / playback tool

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10, Thunderbird all versions. 0-9 come predefined with Thunderbird and these shortcuts are listed on the tags menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to try, but you might be able to combine
a Thunderbird extension with some JavaScript to achieve this
purpose.

The extension is
[tbkeys](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys),
described as :

> tbkeys is an add-on for Thunderbird that uses Mousetrap to bind key sequences to custom commands.

You will find a discussion of the JavaScript in the
Stack Overflow post
[Assign tags above 9 to message in Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385122/assign-tags-above-9-to-message-in-thunderbird).

You will find information and links to documentation in this post.
Here is a small extract:

> To assign a "my tag" to selected messages you can use the following
> code:
>
> ```
> ToggleMessageTag(MailServices.tags.getKeyForTag('my tag'), true);
> ```
>
> Depending on the second argument, the tag will be either added (true)
> or removed (false). For the tbkeys, you will need to use "[Eval
> commands](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys#command-syntax)".